# Fetch field data after creating in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am creating an activation code after user registered , and I want to fetch that code after creating , all the codes are created in database but I can not fetch that code in event,this is my code:

```
    public function __construct(User $user)
     {

    $this->user = $user;
    $this->activationCode = ActivationCode::createCode($user)->code;

    dd( ActivationCode::createCode($user)->code);

      }
```

My error is :

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$code
```

How can I fetch code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `value()` method:

```
ActivationCode::createCode($user)->latest()->value('code')
```

Or get the object first:

```
ActivationCode::createCode($user)->first()->latest()->code;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I can fetch the code for that user , but not the code which just created , I fetch first record for that user!

Comment: If you need the latest one, just add `->latest()` method. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thnaks,It worked with:  ActivationCode::createCode($user)->first()->latest()->code;

Comment: @amini.swallow it couldn't work, you need to add `latest()` before the `first()`, then it will work. Please check.